# How can I get netsuite inventory item historical pricing matrix from systemnotes?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to write a routine that will look over netsuite pricing changes, looking for data that was lost due to buggy code.

My current suitescript code

```
// Define filters
            var filters = [];
            filters.push(new nlobjSearchFilter( 'internalid', null, 'is', id));

            // Define search columns
            var columns = [
                new nlobjSearchColumn( 'itemid' ),
                new nlobjSearchColumn( 'class' ),
                new nlobjSearchColumn( 'name' ),
                new nlobjSearchColumn( 'displayname' ),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('date', 'systemNotes'),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('name', 'systemNotes'),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('type', 'systemNotes'),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('field', 'systemNotes'),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('context', 'systemNotes'),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('newvalue', 'systemNotes'),
                new nlobjSearchColumn('oldvalue', 'systemNotes')
            ];

            var searchResults = nlapiSearchRecord( 'inventoryitem', null, filters, columns );

            var searchResultJson = [];
            _.each(searchResults, function (searchResult){
                if(searchResult.getValue(columns[7]) === "pricelist")
                    searchResultJson.push({
                        itemid:  searchResult.getValue(columns[0]),
                        class: searchResult.getValue(columns[1]),
                        name: searchResult.getValue(columns[2]),
                        displayname: searchResult.getValue(columns[3]),
                        date: searchResult.getValue(columns[4]),
                        username: searchResult.getValue(columns[5]),
                        type: searchResult.getValue(columns[6]),
                        field: searchResult.getValue(columns[7]),
                        context: searchResult.getValue(columns[8]),
                        newvalue: searchResult.getValue(columns[9]),
                        oldvalue: searchResult.getValue(columns[10])
                    });
            });
            return searchResultJson;
```

This gives me a javascript object like

```
class:"136"
context:"UI"
date:"4/29/2016 2:51 am"
displayname:"<item name>"
field:"pricelist"
itemid:"<item id>"
name:"<item id>"
newvalue:"View"
oldvalue:"View"
type:"Change"
username:"<user id>"
```

I want to get the full pricing matrix for the old and new values, but all I'm getting back is the string `View`.  Changes to single fields do return the actual value for newvalue and oldvalue, but the pricelist field just returns `View`.

How can I get the pricing data that is show in the UI of the item's system notes when 'View' is clicked?

Comment: Just be be sure, `pricelist` is `field`, and not `type`?

Comment: yes, i believe so - this field contains the pricing matrix for locations and quantities

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code looks right to me, it should be able to pull multiple rows if they exist.  I would just give you two things to try.

1) Do a search in NetSuite using UI with exact make sure you are getting multiple rows with the same criteria.  Throw in a `nlapiLogExecution` in your code to get the `filter` values and then the length of the `searchResults`.

2) The syntax below is a search that definitely pulls multiple rows if they exist, although more verbose than your code.

```
                    var searchResultSalesInfo = new Array();
                    var filterSalesInfo = new Array();
                    var columnSalesInfo = new Array();
                    filterSalesInfo [0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('entity', null , 'is', entityInternalId);
                    columnSalesInfo [0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('total');
                    columnSalesInfo [1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custbody_bcg_contract_book');
                    columnSalesInfo [2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('trandate');
                    columnSalesInfo [3] = new nlobjSearchColumn('item');
                    columnSalesInfo [4] = new nlobjSearchColumn('displayname', 'item');
                    columnSalesInfo [5] = new nlobjSearchColumn('rate');
                    columnSalesInfo [6] = new nlobjSearchColumn('quantity');


                    var searchResultSalesInfo = nlapiSearchRecord('salesorder', null, filterSalesInfo, columnSalesInfo);
                    var amount = [];
                    var bookCode = [];
                    var tranDate = [];
                    var items = [];
                    var itemName =[];
                    var rate = [];
                    var quantity = [];


                   // push all info to arrays      
                    for (var x = 0; x < searchResultSalesInfo.length; x++){
                          var pattern2015 = new RegExp("2015");
                          if (pattern2015.test(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getText(columnSalesInfo[1])) == true){  
                                amount.push(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getValue(columnSalesInfo[0]));
                                bookCode.push(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getText(columnSalesInfo[1]));
                                tranDate.push(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getValue(columnSalesInfo[2]));
                                items.push(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getText(columnSalesInfo[3]));
                                itemName.push(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getValue(columnSalesInfo[4]));
                                rate.push(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getValue(columnSalesInfo[5]));
                                quantity.push(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getValue(columnSalesInfo[6]));
                          }
                          else
                          nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','Pattern Not Matching', pattern2015.test(searchResultSalesInfo[x].getText(columnSalesInfo[1]))+ ' ' +searchResultSalesInfo[x].getText(columnSalesInfo[1]))
                    }
```